# .htaccess: http://www redirects to www.www

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to solve my issue with .htaccess file. I found out that accessing my page with http://www.example.com redirects to https://www.www.example.com.

I have tried numerous .htaccess rules and can't figure it out.
I want to redirect http to https and non www to www.

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I tried separate rules or reversing order (first to https then add www) but I'm still getting double www.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edited to work the way you asked.

Try this as your configuration in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm getting too many redirects with this syntax. Reverting back to your first works again. Im also removing /public from .htacces after your 2 lines with RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L] and RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's a browser problem. I used Justin's rule and it works good in Safari but on Chrome it's getting double www.www still.
Anyways it isn't related to .htaccess as I though first and was scratching my head why it's not working.

Comment: Try clearing your cache on Chrome.  It may be remembering the previous 301 Response from Apache

Comment: One more note. It *was* related to your first .htaccess.  You had “hard-coded” a “www.” into the 301 redirect response, so it was concatenating the “www.” to the new URL.  Using the example I gave and clearing your browser cache / doing a hard page reload will fix it.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to clear cache. I want to redirect all request to www but without www.www when someones goes to http://www.

Comment: Okay, so you want all requests (both http and https) to example.com that don't have a "www." to end up as *https://www.example.com*?

Comment: Both http and https to be redirected to www.example.com (without http://www.example.com being redirected to www.www)

Comment: I modified the answer.  Try using that in your .htaccess and it should work as you explained.  Don't forget to clear cache :)