# .htaccess rewrites results in www.www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

What I want to achieve should be quite simple:

Redirect all traffic to `HTTPS` and the `www.` subdomain.  And to achieve this I used the following rule:

```
# Canonical https/www
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.domain.com [NC]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, if I follow a link like this:

`http://www.example.com`

I end up here:

`https://www.www.example.com`

So then I found this question: [.htaccess: http://www redirects to www.www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461656/htaccess-http-www-redirects-to-www-www)

And I completely replaced the rule I used above with the rule suggested in the accepted answer:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However now I get the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error, and the site completely refuses to load.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: The second rewrite condition in the first attempt will capture the "www" as `%1`. So obviously the rewriting rule will then generate "www.www"...

Comment: In the second attempt you face the issue that the condition will certainly also match the "www variant" of the host name, so you will certainly experience a rewriting loop...

Answer (score 0):

Check this rewrite in your .htaccess file, maybe it help

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```